# mv: cannot move file to '': No such file or directory in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have following command

```
mv 15827.png  "$(<15827.png.txt)"
```

Which is moving the file 18827.png to the path specified in 15827.png.txt, and it is working fine.

But when I moved this command to shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
mv 15827.png  "$(<15827.png.txt)"
```

I'm running it with:

```
sh myscript.sh
```

Its not working and I am getting following error:

> mv: cannot move '15827.png' to '': No such file or directory

The file `15827.png.txt` contains the digit `7` and there is folder named `7` in the current directory.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: the file `15827.png.txt` is empty.

Comment: 15827.png.txt is not empty

Comment: Something must have emptied it between the time that you tested the first command and ran the script.

Comment: No, after executing command also I have checked the txt file, its not empty

Comment: Its working when I am writing those commands in terminal

Comment: The best way to debug shell scripts is to put `set -x` at the beginning, it will then show every line as it's being executed, with all the expansions done.

Comment: Are you running the script in the same directory that you did the test?

Comment: I am getting it as + set -x mv 15827.png

Comment: I am running on the same directory where I did it on the terminal, before doing it in shell script i copied back the images to current location

Comment: Put `cat 15827.png.txt` before the `mv` line to see what the file contains

Comment: cat 15827.png.txt  mv 15827.png  "$(<15827.png.txt)"  Like this ??

Comment: 15827.png.txt contains 7 and there is forlder named 7

Comment: The script really begins with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: What if you change it to `mv 15827.png "$(cat 15827.png.txt)"`?

Comment: the script starts with #!/bin/bash

Comment: and i am running like `sh myscript.sh`

Comment: That's your problem, it should be `bash myscript.sh` or just `./myscript.sh`

Comment: You're using `bash` syntax but you're running it with `sh` instead of `bash`.

Comment: mv 15827.png "$(cat 15827.png.txt)"?   THIS WORKED !!!

Comment: `$(<filename)` is a `bash` extension, it's not usable in `sh`.

Comment: Why are you running it with `sh` instead of `bash`?

Comment: I was running all by scripts using sh and it was working also, I  was not aware about this thing.

Comment: Your other scripts must not use bash-only extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're running the script with `sh`, but it needs to be run with `bash`, because `$(<filename)` is a `bash` extension.

Make the script executable:

```
chmod 755 myscript.sh
```

and then run it with:

```
./myscript.sh
```

This will execute the script using the shell named in the `#!` line.